# WCF service is unable to call service on another machine

Tags: wcf, networking

Here's the situation setup: multiple WCF services are hosted on IIS on several virtual machines inside one sub-network. Let's imagine we have:

- virtual machine A with IP address 10.0.8.100
- virtual machine B with IP address 10.0.8.101
- virtual machine C with IP address 10.0.8.102

A, B and C are within the same domain.

Machine A have WCF service responsible for authentication, and both machines B and C have services calling this auth service.

Used binding

```
<binding name="WsHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService" 
     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
     sendTimeout="00:10:00"
     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
<security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>
```

Everything works just fine until one day, when single call of auth service on machine A from both machines B and C fails with exception:

```
An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. 
See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
```

Inner exception says:

```
An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
```

Meanwhile, this service can be accessed by its address in browser and I can successfully ping any machine from any other machine.

I know that this exception most frequently is caused by time skew more than WCF default of 5 mins. I have faced this issue before, but this is a different case, because time on all virtual machines is synced and time zone is chosen correctly.

Interesting tip: I've tried to relocate mentioned auth service from A to B, than call it from C and I did not get this exception.

I suspect that something was changed in the network layout/settings etc. and led to this situation, but I don't have any solid proof, because network administrators are out of reach at the moment.

Again - everything was working fine and no updates were delivered into this environment during the last month.

Where should I look for any clues about reasons of this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: For security reasons, the actual cause of such errors is usually not returned to the client. In order to determine the actual cause, you need to check the specific error cause in the server log. For web services that use WS-Security, If the time difference between the timestamp in the message and the server clock is too large, it will trigger the service to return a security error. Without knowing the reason for the service record, we can only guess where the problem is. Ideally, you should try to get the server-side details.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that time skew was actually the reason of this exception. All virtual machines are configured to display time in AM/PM format, and the time skew was exactly 12 hour. This feature was not taken into account because we usually use 24-hour format.
Case closed.